# Datatables use XML for serverside response

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatables

I have a custom web service that i have made to answer a datatables call (to handle paging and search)

According to the docs, I tried to use the ajax.dataSrc as a function to manyaly parse the xml data to the expected format.

```
$("#MyTable").dataTable({
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            url: urlRoot + "/WS/XXXX/YYYYY",
            dataSrc: function (data) {
                console.log("data");
                console.log(data);
            },
            type: "POST"
        }
    });
```

However the dataSrc function is not even called and i'm granted with a messagebox alert saying the JSON is invalid ...

Answer below :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the datatable jquery ajax call was configured with the `dataType: "json"`inside the datatables plugin itself, causing the ajax call to fall in the error case as the server header replied with a `text/html` content type...

The solution was to add `dataType: "text",` in the ajax options to override this behavior, as follow :

```
$("#IncidentTable").dataTable({
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            url: urlRoot + "/WS/XXXX/YYYYY",
            dataType: "text",
            dataSrc: function (data) {
                console.log("data");
                console.log(data);
            },
            type: "POST"
        }
    });
```

And then the dataSrc is correcly called, allowin to manualy parse the data as we want.